# Rails 3.2: Ruby date logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails app where I need to check date(s)(dd/mm) from several models in my database and trigger a mailer 2 weeks before, 1 week before, and 1 day before each date. How could I write this logic in my app (rails 3.2)?

*Note - I plan on using a rake task to check whether and mails need to be sent out.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with scopes:

```rb
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :two_weeks_before, lambda{|the_date| where('my_date between ? and ?', 2.weeks.until(the_date), the_date)}
  scope :one_week_before, lambda{|the_date| where('my_date between ? and ?', 1.week.until(the_date), the_date)}
  scope :the_day_before, lambda{|the_date| where('my_date between ? and ?', 1.day.until(the_date), the_date)}
  scope :undelivered, where(:delivered => false)
end

# usage:
MyModel.two_weeks_before(Date.tomorrow).undelivered.all.each do |model|
  MyMailer.notification(model).deliver
  model.update_attribute(:delivered, true)
end
```

The date ranges grab all models with a date in the 2 weeks before, you can adjust the endpoints as necessary, obv.

Comment: so add these scopes to each of the models i need to search and then use the second part of your answer in a mailer?.. Sorry, new to rails and actionamiler...Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I'd go with putting the second part in the rake task. The mailer should just be responsible for mailing, not finding records.

Comment: Thanks!.. How would i go about the undelivered => false part.. add a  boolean column to my model?

Comment: Also, the date in one of my models it names "anniversary_date".. what parts of your answer do i replace with that? Everywhere it says "the_date"

Answer (score 1):

2 weeks before, compare date with this:

```
Model.where("my_date between ? and ?", Date.today - 15, Date.today - 14)
```

1 week, to this:

```
Model.where("my_date between ? and ?", Date.today - 8, Date.today - 7)
```

Try in your console and see the results.

Comment: cool that works.. it gives me dates such as "between '2012-06-05' and '2012-06-06'".. but how would i only check the mm/dd .. it needs to disregard year

Comment: I believe there is no difference between comparing 2 dates with and without years, as the result is a difference in the number of days.